# consecutive xmlXPathEval's with libxml2

Tags: html, xml, xpath, libxml2

I'm using libxml2 to parse a html document and I got a question.
What's the difference between

```
xmlXPathObjectPtr obj = xmlXPathEval((xmlChar*)"//div[@id='gall_list']//td//h3/img[@alt]", ctx);
printf("%d", obj->nodesetval->nodeNr);
```

and

```
xmlXPathObjectPtr obj1 = xmlXPathEval((xmlChar*)"//div[@id='gall_list']//td//h3", ctx);
xmlXPathObjectPtr obj2 = xmlXPathEval((xmlChar*)"img[@alt]", ctx);
printf("%d", obj2->nodesetval->nodeNr);
```

?
If I'm correct, they're supposed to be the same, right? But the second one is not working correctly. I've changed the "img[@alt]" part of the obj2 part to "./img[@alt]", but it didn't work either.

Can anybody let me know what's wrong with the second one? Just FYI, the following one worked correctly:

```
xmlXPathObjectPtr obj1 = xmlXPathEval((xmlChar*)"//div[@id='gall_list']//td", ctx);
xmlXPathObjectPtr obj2 = xmlXPathEval((xmlChar*)".//h3/img[@alt]", ctx);
printf("%d", obj2->nodesetval->nodeNr);
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first two code snippets should definitely behave differently since xmlXPathEval operates on the same context node for both expressions. In your third snippet you are searching for all descendants (//) of the context node, if this node is the document element then all img elements with alt attributes inside a h3 element will be returned. The context does not change automatically based on the result from the first call.

It is possible to set the context node yourself through the `node` field of `xmlXPathContext` like in the following snippet. Note that I translated this from vala and did not check type names.

```
xmlXPathObjectPtr obj1 = xmlXPathEval((xmlChar*)"//div[@id='gall_list']//td//h3", ctx);
xmlXPathNodeSetPtr nodeset = obj1->nodesetval;
xmlNodePtr node = nodeset->item(0);

// Set the context node for the following xpath expressions
ctx.node = node;
xmlXPathObjectPtr obj2 = xmlXPathEval((xmlChar*)"img[@alt]", ctx);
```

Comment: örn: Thanks for the answer, Jörn. That was exactly what I was looking for and it works like a charm. It would be better if there was a more convenient way to apply an xpath query to multiple nodes resulted from the previous execution of xmlXPathEval() though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking at the [docs for xmlXPathEval()](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xpath.html#xmlXPathEval) and I can't see a reason why the first two code blocks above should do the same thing: In other words, why should the XPath processor's context in evaluating the second XPath be affected by the evaluation of the first? The doc doesn't say that xmlXPathEval() will change the passed-in context... Does xmlXPathEval() do that?

Seems to me what you would need to do, in order to get your second code example to work, is to pass in a ctx that is based on obj1 (the result of the first xmlXPathEval()) as the second argument to the second xmlXPathEval(). However I can't see how to derive an xmlXPathContextPtr from an xmlXPathObjectPtr.

The reason your 3rd code example "works" is that the result of the first XPath evaluation is ignored; the XPath expression `.//h3/img[@alt]` will select the specified `<img>` elements when the context is simply the root node (`/`). But it will match **all** img elements that are children of h3 elements and that have an alt attribute, **not only** those that are descendants of `div[@id='gall_list']`.

Comment: +1 Good answer. I agree: it's not clear that `xmlXPathEval()` do change the context pointer argument. Maybe this function could work http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xpointer.html#xmlXPtrNewContext

Comment: @Alejandro - good idea. I guess we then just need a way to get from an xmlXPathObjectPtr to an xmlNodePtr.

Comment: xmlXPathObjectPtr -> xmlNodeSetPtr -> xmlNodePtr (array from 0 to xmlNodeSetPtr -> nodeNr)

Comment: @Alej: looks like @Jörn figured out a way to do it. +1 to him.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, LarsH. You're right. xmlXPathEval() doesn't change the passed-in context.